# listener for contentView

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

is there a listener or some way to determine when contentView is created?   I have used other type listeners and they work for other child views inside of content view.  however content view is different.  I have not yet found anything that works.

Comment: that answers 70% of the question but the other 30% of the answer is,  in order for the onContentChanged() method to work a view.post runnable is needed on the view to wait until the view is able to get the height  or width.  without that it will not work even if you use the onContentChanged() method, so I was going to post my answer to explain this,  however since you asked and you did answer most of the question I will check it again now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [onContentChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onContentChanged%28%29) yet?

The documentation says

> This hook is called whenever the content view of the screen changes (due to a call to Window.setContentView or Window.addContentView).